# Difference between a chrome popup and Panel

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am building an extension for Chrome and Can't decide If I should use chrome.windows.create  type popup , panel or detached panel. I could not find a comparative study of the three options . Any links or short description of positives and limitations of each will be helpful . 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Since chrome doesn't by default enable panels , this need to be set to display panel behavior instead of popup window . Note that popup windows can be re positioned and one can view console window , but none of it is available in panel .

Answer (score 4):

You are having difficulty understanding it, because unless you specifically enabled an experimental feature, they are *exactly the same*, or rather the latter ones are ignored and a `popup` type is created.
Unfortunately, this means that this API is unavailable for general use until Google decides to mark it stable.

Quoting the [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#method-create):

> The 'panel' and 'detached_panel' types create a popup unless the '--enable-panels' flag is set.

As for what panels are, here is the [API proposal](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/extensions/proposed-changes/apis-under-development/panels) with detailed description.

> Panels are windows that are visible to the user even while the user is interacting with other applications. The small windows are positioned at the bottom of the screen, with minimal manual window management by the user. This API will allow extension developers to create and use panels.
>
> [...]
>
> An extension opens small "pop up" windows, for example, separate chat sessions, calculator, media player, stock/sport/news ticker, task list, scratchpad, that the user wants to keep visible while using a different application or browsing a different web site. Scattered "pop up" windows are difficult for the user to keep track of, therefore panels are placed along the bottom of the screen and are "always on top".
>
> The user would like easy control of chat windows: finding them, moving them out of the way, etc. Window management of separate chat "pop ups" is time consuming. All panels can be minimized/maximized together.

If you want a real-life example, the [Hangouts extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hangouts/nckgahadagoaajjgafhacjanaoiihapd) is whitelisted to use this window type; that's how they make the chat panels:

[image: Hangouts screenshot]